# ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException even when app transitions from a user-visible state (Activity)

Tags: android, foreground-service

I need to start a service to allow background audio playing when the user backgrounds the app:

```
val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent)
```

This is fired in an Activity as the app is backgrounded. I'm detecting backgrounding apps by registering a LifecycleObserver and using this method:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun onAppBackgrounded() {
    // notify listeners
}
```

The background notify is working correctly, but I'm still getting the exception, even though:

> Your app transitions from a user-visible state, such as an activity.

As described here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions

What exactly does "transitions from a user-visible state" mean, and am I using it correctly here? Unfortunately, I can't reproduce and it's only showing on Firebase.

Comment: "I'm detecting backgrounding apps by registering a LifecycleObserver and using this method" -- what lifecycle are you observing? If it is `ProcessLifecycleOwner`, that waits 700ms before firing `ON_STOP`, to make sure that no other activity starts first and to deal with configuration changes. That might be too long of a gap between when you left the foreground from a system standpoint.

Comment: @CommonsWare yea its `ProcessLifecycleOwner`. what else could i use to avoid the delay? or another alternative

Comment: Start the foreground service when the user takes some action that might lead to your needing it. For example, a music player might start the foreground service when it starts playing music.

Comment: @CommonsWare i think that's a fair solution but I don't understand how this doesn't fit the criteria of "Your app transitions from a user-visible state, such as an activity." Wish there was more documentation on this.